# How to change CupertinoButton background color only when onPressed is called

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I have tried following code but it does not change the color of the button only when it is pressed.

```
//class attribute
Color bgColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;

//Widget
CupertinoButton(
  color: bgColor,
  child: Text('LOGIN', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto',)),
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
  onPressed: () {
  this.setState(() {
    bgColor = Colors.black;  
  });
  print(_emailValue);
  print(_passwordValue);
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/products');
  },
),
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color permanently after onPressed? Or only while pressed?

Comment: @GaboBrandX only when it is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `CupertinoButton` with a `GestureDetector`. Than use the `onTapDown` and `onTapCancel` to change color only when pressed. Like this:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Color _buttonColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print(_emailValue);
              print(_passwordValue);
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/products');
            },
            onTapDown: (tapDetails) {
              setState(() => _buttonColor = Colors.black);
            },
            onTapCancel: () {
              setState(() => _buttonColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent);
            },
            child: CupertinoButton(
              color: _buttonColor,
              child: Text('test'),
              onPressed: () {},
              pressedOpacity: 1.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can use onTap event on GestureDetector for calling navigation or whatever you need.

[image]

Comment: I have wrapped it around GestureDetector now onTapCancel works but not the onTapDown! Should I also wrap the ButtonTheme?

Comment: @AminMemariani Sorry, I've removed the ButtonTheme from my answer, as it's not needed. About the onTapDown event, you're initializing your color variable with deepPurpleAccent. So you should set that color onTapCancel and black onTapDown.

Comment: @AminMemariani Please check my last update. Added the final result also. That should work! :)

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to adjust an opacity of the highlighted button color, you can change `pressedOpacity` property:

```
CupertinoButton(
  pressedOpacity: 0.4,
  ...
```

The default `pressedOpacity` value is `0.1`, which is quite low. I found `0.4` is more natural to native iOS look.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate, there's no way you can do it.
You can extend the CupertinoButton and add the functionality, or use the RawMaterialButton and make it with the appearance that you need.

**Edit**: If you want to permanently change the color of the button, the @sina-seirafi answer is the correct one. But if you want to the button to be black only went you are pressing the RawMaterialButton with the black splash color is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.

You just need to put the "bgColor" outside of the build function, so that when the setState is called, it doesn't set it again back to Purple.

```
Color bgColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: CupertinoButton(
        color: bgColor,
        child: Text(
          'LOGIN',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          ),
        ),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
        onPressed: () {
          this.setState(
            () {
              bgColor = Colors.black;
            },
          );

          // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/products');
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```